# Round-robin scheduler - process twice in the list? Preemptive?

Tags: process, cpu, scheduler, round-robin

Round-robin schedulers normally maintain a list of all runnable processes, with each process occurring exactly once in the list.
**But what would happen if a process occurred twice in the list?**

And is round robin scheduling a preemptive or a non-preemptive scheduling strategy anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In round robin scheduling, all processes in the ready queue are given equal time units. CPU time is divided equally among the processes. So if a process was listed twice, it would be granted twice the CPU time of the other processes.

Source: http://basicofcomputer.com/round_robin_scheduling_algorithm_in_operating_system.htm

Answer (score 0):

If a processor occurs more than once in the round-robin list, then it will get two turns for each pass through the list. One reason for allowing this would be to implement a
primitive priority system since the more times it occurs on the list, the higher the
percentage of time the CPU will spend on that process.

Answer (score 0):

Round Robin Scheduling. Round Robin is the preemptive process scheduling algorithm. Each process is provided a fix time to execute, it is called a quantum. Once a process is executed for a given time period, it is preempted and other process executes for a given time period.

Source: TutorialsPoint (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/operating_system/os_process_scheduling_algorithms.htm)

Comment: Can you please add the link to the source for reference.